# Want to do some stuff when ultracomboeditor got focused

Tags: c#, infragistics

I am using UltraComboEditior of Infragistics Conrtrols in C# winform application, I want to show a messageBox when UltroComboEditior got focues by MouseClick or KeyBoard Tab button, how can I do it? Any suggestions ? I tried BeforeDropDown but it is called only when we click on arrow button to show drop down list but I am using only drop down with auto complete option set to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UltraComboEditor control has "Enter" event which fires when the control becomes the active control of the form, and this event will fire in both situations - when the control got focus by using your Tab key, and when you are using your mouse.

I hope that this will help you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it inherit the [OnGotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ongotfocus.aspx) event which you can subscribe to?

Comment: No it doesn't inherit the OnGotFocus event :(